# How to marshal the following c++ method into c#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

We need to import native c## methods in c#, but we don't know how to marshal the code correctly. Especially we don't know which datatypes to use.

Are the used datatypes in the dll import correct?

```
VDLL32 LS_STATUS_CODE VMSWINAPI MyMethodToImport(
      unsigned char LSFAR *server_name, /*  IN */
      VLSservInfo   LSFAR *srv_info,  /* out */
      unsigned char LSFAR *unused1,   /*reserved*/
      unsigned long LSFAR *unused2    /*reserved*/
   );
```

For C# we used the following:

```
[DllImport(LibraryName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "MyMethodToImport", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
                public static extern int MyMethodToImport(ref VLSservInfo servInfo, IntPtr serverName);
```

The current result is empty, so serverName is not interpreted correctly inside the native dll
I expect a not empty ServInfo object, but the actual output is empty.

Comment: The parameter order doesn't seem to match.

Comment: The server name is first.  unsigned char is pretty unusual for an argument that looks like a string, but anything with "VMS" in the name is likely to be very old and char used to be unsigned in the good old days.   So use string instead of IntPtr.  You can't omit the "unused" arguments, use IntPtr and pass IntPtr.Zero.  Don't ignore the return value, it ought to give you an error indication.  If "winapi" is somewhat trustworthy then it is CallingConvention.Stdcall.

Comment: Fwiw, intentionally obfuscating a published api by a company like Gemalto is a very bad idea.